# Using jQuery in Prestashop CMS page

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, prestashop

I'm trying to use a bit of code in a CMS page, I put the bit of code in the end of the html code implemented in the CMS page that I created in Prestashop Backoffice, however, parts of that code work but the rest of the code doesn't work and don't know why.

So basically I have a page with a list and some divs inside of each item of the list. So with jQuery I hide all the DIVs (and this particular part works) and then in each item that I click I have a jQuery function to toggle visibility of the DIV beneath. So the problem is here, that bit of code seems that doesn't work, and I don't know why.

```
<h1>Cursos Magic Nails</h1>
<p>Temos um vasto leque de ofertas formativas à sua espera. Escolha um dos links abaixo e veja a nossa oferta formativa.</p>
<ul id="portefolio">
<li><img name="" src="" width="256" height="200" alt="" />Unhas
<div class="infos">
<h3>Cursos de Unhas de Gel e Acrílico</h3>
<ul>
     <li>Curso de Técnicas de Unhas de Gel</li>
        <li>Designer de Unhas de Gel</li>
        <li>Curso de Art-Nail</li>
        <li>Reciclagem para Profissionais</li>
</ul>
<ul>
     <li>Curso de Acrílico</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li><img name="" src="" width="256" height="200" alt="" />Manicure/Pedicure
<div class="infos">
<h3>Cursos de Manicure/Pedicure</h3>
<ul>
     <li>Curso de Manicure</li>
        <li>Curso de Pedicure</li>
        <li>Pack 3 Cursos (Manicure/Pedicure e Depilação)</li>
        <li>Curso 3 em 1<span>PROMO</span></li>
        <li>Manicure e Pedicure<span>PROMO</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li><img name="" src="" width="256" height="200" alt="" />Pestanas
<div class="infos"> 
<h3>Cursos de Pestanas</h3>
<ul>
<li>Curso de Alongamento de Pestanas<span>NOVO</span></li>
<li>Curso de Permanente de Pestanas<span>NOVO</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li><img name="" src="" width="256" height="200" alt="" />Depilação
<div class="infos">
<h3>Cursos de Depilação</h3>
<ul>
<li>Curso de Depilação</li>
<li>Curso de Depilação com Linha<span>NOVO</span></li>
<li>Curso de Depilação<span>PROMO</span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>Pack 3 Cursos</li>
<li>Curso 3 em 1<span>PROMO</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li><img name="" src="" width="256" height="200" alt="" />Massagens
<div class="infos">
<h3>Cursos de Massagens</h3>
<ul>
<li>Curso de Massagens de Relaxamento</li>
<li>Curso de Massagens das Pedras Quentes</li>
<li>Curso de Massagens de Estética</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li><img name="" src="" width="256" height="200" alt="" />Rosto
<div class="infos">
<h3>Cursos de Rosto</h3>
<ul>
<li>Curso de Rosto</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li><img name="" src="" width="256" height="200" alt="" />Glitter Tattoo
<div class="infos">
<h3>Cursos de Glitter Tattoo</h3>
<ul>
<li>Curso de Glitter Tattoo</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery embedded in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        //Hide that DIV
        $('#page #portefolio li .infos').hide(); //Hide/close all containers


        //On Click
        $('#page #portefolio li').click(function(){
            //If immediate next container is closed...
            if($(this).parent('#page #portefolio li .infos').is(':hidden')){ 
                $('#page #portefolio li').removeClass('active').parent('#page #portefolio li .infos').slideUp();
                $(this).addClass('active').parent('#page #portefolio li .infos').slideDown();   
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active').parent('#page #portefolio li .infos').slideUp();
            }
            return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
        });
    });
</script>
```

So the part above //On Click is the part that doesn't work.

You can test that in this link:
[Link](http://magicnails.designeart.net/content/11-cursos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is the way you're traversing to find the right `.infos` divs. jQuery has pretty elegant traversal methods that can make this a lot simpler.

Here's a live example: http://jsfiddle.net/WbUPt/1/

```
// Cache your jQuery selector... you don't need to find it over and over again
var $portefolio = $('#portefolio');

// Hide / close all containers
$portefolio.find('.infos').hide(); 

// Add a single event to the container for better performance
$portefolio.on('click', 'li', function (event) {

    var $this = $(event.currentTarget);

    if ($this.hasClass('active')) {

        // Deactivate
        $this.removeClass('active');
        $this.find('.infos').slideUp();

    } else {

        // Activate
        $this.addClass('active');
        $this.find('.infos').slideDown();
    }
});
```

​